# I am stuck I cannot insert data into MySQL database from JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysql-workbench

I want to do simple signup form, but I cannot go forward, i have tried everything and it still does not work this is my code:

```
protected void doPost(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException
    {
        StringBuilder builder= new StringBuilder();
        Reader reader=request.getReader();
        int c;
        while ((c=reader.read())!=-1)
        {
            builder.append((char) c);
        }
        String signup=builder.toString();
        try {
            JSONObject object= new JSONObject(signup);
            String name=object.getString("username");
            String email=object.getString("email");
            String pass=object.getString("pass");
            String sql="INSERT INTO user_f VALUES("+email+","+name+","+pass+")"+";";

            statement.executeUpdate(sql);
            //ResultSet set= statement.executeQuery("SELECT ")

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

My Error Stack I edited the code so many times and I am kinda getting frustrated this the error that I am getting :

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com,dsf,sdfsd)' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:939)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2478)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2625)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2547)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeLargeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:2605)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1469)
    at com.herda.app.Servlet.doPost(Servlet.java:56)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: you need to add quotes around the values, or use PreparedStatement

Comment: thanks mate, now it is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your MySQL query does not have a valid syntax as the error is saying. You need quotes around string literals. Try something like this:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO user_f VALUES(\"" + email + "\", \"" + name + "\", \"" + pass + "\");";
```

However, be aware that this code is open to SQL injections! To resolve this security issue, you can use prepared statements. That also resolves the quote problem for you.

Comment: Thank you man, it works like charm. Just one question what does the slashes represent?

Comment: @johndoe, the \ characters escape the quotes within your string. If you do not add them, they will terminate your Java string instead of being added as a character in the query.

Comment: @johndoe, if your problem has been resolved, please accept the answer so others can see that as well.

Comment: Here you go I am new to StackOverflow :)

Comment: Strings should be quoted in single quotes for maximum portability (it is in the SQL standard and supported by most databases), but really don't use this answer as the solution: you need to use a prepared statement.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, he specifially mentioned MySQL, so I think both are usable in this case. I mentioned the prepared statement as well, but in my opinion it would not be a valid answer without the actual problem being solved.

Comment: Although I agree that you should explain what is wrong with his code, teaching people how they should really solve this problem correctly is preferable over showing them how to do the wrong/insecure thing correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You shoud test your sql query fist. execute it on MySql Workbench

I think it should be

```
String sql="INSERT INTO user_f VALUES('"+email+"','"+name+"','"+pass+"')"+";";
```

Comment: Could you mark my answer as answered. You and me need 50 reputation to make comment :(

Comment: I know @Mike :(  Don't worry we will get there

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are missing quotes around your values, however you should **never** construct queries like this by concatenating values in to the query string. It opens your code to SQL injection (eg when you are inserting user input), which is a very big security risk. Instead you should use a prepared statement with parameter placeholders. This will take care of escaping values so SQL injection won't be a problem.

Prepared statements on some database systems also have the added value of leading to better performance because the statement can be reused.

As an example:

```
try (PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(
           "INSERT INTO user_f(email,name,pass) VALUES(?,?,?)")) {
    pstmt.setString(1, email);
    pstmt.setString(2, name);
    pstmt.setString(3, pass);
    pstmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

In this answer I have also explicitly listed the columns you are inserting, this makes your code more future proof (for example when you add or remove columns).